# Integrating Google Calendar data with D3.js based Calendar

Tags: javascript, d3.js, google-calendar-api, cal-heatmap

I initially began this endeavor with an implementation of fullCalendar.js which worked as intended. However, problems arose when I started to customize the UI. After much toil, I decided to scrap the implemention of fullcalendar and go for something more flexible in terms of visuals.

I have been working with javascript for a number of years and have become familiar with the basics. I do not consider myself an expert (at least not yet). D3.js offers more flexibility as far as crafting visuals is concerned but I seem to have hit a wall as far as my expertise is concerned. Integrating Google's Calendar API (to render calendar data in the d3 interface) is presenting quite the problem for me. I feel I have hit a bit of a wall as far as my understanding is concerned.

I'm using Cal-Heatmap (which is based on d3 v3) to get the calendar up and running. My problem lies in integrating googles calendar data. To be honest I do not know where to start or how best to go about it. I don't have much experience working with API's in javascript and am continuing to research how best to do it.

In the meantime, I'm posting this to the community for some guidance. I hope to learn from this and improve my knowledge and expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you can check out the [quickstart projects](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview#quickstarts) provided in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview) to understand the API better.

To play around and see what the API can do, without writing any code, visit the [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/calendar/v3/). Try using `calendar.events.list`, with your Google email as the calendar ID. (You'll need to enable [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) authorization.)

When you're already comfortable with the usage of the API, you can visit [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) which has examples implementing [Calendar Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar) inspired by the D3 calendar visualization.

Comment: Worked out pretty well, though I had to discard work on the project due to shifting priorities. I am planning on implementing this in a new project so this will still be helpful, thanks!